# How to set a timeout to a RabbitMQ RPC request?

Tags: go, rabbitmq, rpc, amqp

Is there any timeout to publish messages to a topic in the AMQP (RabbitMQ) RPC model?

I don't want to wait for a long time (after a timeout) for the consumer's answer to the producer message.

Reference: [RPC (Go RabbitMQ Client)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-go.html)

Answer (score 0):

(example code uses [`streadway/amqp`](https://github.com/streadway/amqp))

You can achieve this by using **a timer**, which can be as short as you wish it to be. Then wait on both the RPC response and the timer channels with a `select` statement:

```
func doRPC() ([]byte, error) {
    // ...RPC setup code
    timer := time.NewTimer(2 * time.Second)
    for {
        // waits until either a response from the RPC server
        // is available or the timer expires
        select {
        case msg := <-msgs: // msgs is of type <-chan amqp.Delivery
            if msg.CorrelationId == correlationID {
                return msg.Body, nil
            }

        case <-timer.C:
            return nil, errors.New("waiting for RPC response timed out or was cancelled")
        }
    }
}
```

To yield control of the timeout to the caller, instead of a timer you can use **a context**. It works in the same way, except that now you select on the context `Done()` channel:

```
func caller() {
    // the caller can create a context with the desired timeout
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2 * time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    doRPC(ctx)
}

func doRPC(ctx context.Context) ([]byte, error) {
    // ...RPC setup code
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <-msgs: // msgs is of type <-chan amqp.Delivery
            if msg.CorrelationId == correlationID {
                return msg.Body, nil
            }

        case <-ctx.Done():
            return nil, errors.New("waiting for RPC response timed out or was cancelled")
        }
    }
}
```